# Задача "Степень"

Tags: c++, оптимизация, производительность, олимпиада, теория-чисел

Дана задача:

> Для того чтобы проверить, как её ученики умеют считать, Мария Ивановна каждый год задаёт им на дом одну и ту же задачу — для заданного натурального A найти минимальное натуральное N такое, что N в степени N (N, умноженное на себя N раз) делится на A. Необходимо написать программу, решающую эту задачу

---

`1 ≤ A ≤ 10^9`
Я написал такой код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;
vector<int> decomp (int n)
{
    vector<int> ans (0);
    int d = 2;
    while (d * d <= n)
    {
        if (n % d == 0)
        {
            ans.push_back(d);
            n /= d;
        }
        else
            d += 1;
    }
    if (n > 1)
        ans.push_back(n);
    return ans;
}
int main()
{
    int x; cin >> x;
    if (x == 1)
        cout << 1;
    else
    {
        vector<int> tmp = decomp(x);
        unordered_set<int> s;
        for (int el: tmp)
            s.insert(el);
        vector<int> a (0);
        for (int el: s)
            a.push_back(el);
        int y = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
            y *= a[i];
        if (y >= 29)
            cout << y;
        else
        {
            int k = 1; int n = k * y;
            while ((int)pow(n, n) % x != 0)
            {
                n = k * y;
                k += 1;
            }
            cout << n;
        }
    }
}
```

Но он выполняется слишком медленно. Помогите пожалуйста, как можно его оптимизировать?

Comment: использовать для поиска простых делителей что-то быстрее? Например решето Эрастосфена?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184457,
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1419854, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1140975

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Помогите решить задачу. Степени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1184457/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%a1%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ну, например, так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

map<unsigned int, unsigned int> factor(unsigned int A)
{
    map<unsigned int,unsigned int> m;
    while(A%2 == 0) { m[2]++; A /= 2; };
    for(unsigned int i = 3; i*i <= A; i += 2)
    {
        while(A%i == 0) { m[i]++; A /= i; };
    }
    if (A != 1) m[A]++;
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    unsigned int A;
    cin >> A;
    if (A == 1) { cout << "1\n"; return 0; }
    auto m = factor(A);
    unsigned int p = 1;
    unsigned int e = 0;
    for(const auto& v: m)
    {
        p *= v.first;
        if (v.second > e) e = v.second;
        //cout << v.first << " ** " << v.second << endl;
    }
    if (p < e)
    {
        unsigned int N = ((e+p-1)/p)*p;
        unsigned int M = p, k = 1;

        while(M*k < e)
        {
            for(const auto& v: m)
            {
                if (v.second == e)
                {
                    M *= v.first;
                    k++;
                }
            }
        }
        cout << ((M < N) ? M : N) << endl;
    }
    else cout << p << endl;
}
```